# How to completely remove virsh from Ubuntu

Tags: 13.10, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

How to uninstall virsh from Ubuntu 13.10 server. I have already removed libvirt-bin, qemu and kvm but virsh is still running. I used following command to remove libvirt-bin.

```
apt-get remove --purge libvirt-bin kvm qemu qemu-system-x86
apt-get autoremove
reboot
```

also tried

```
apt-get remove virsh
```

but didn't work

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package virsh
```

Thanks,

Comment: Well, package `virsh` [doesn't seem to exist](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=virsh&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all). Maybe you want to uninstall something else?

Comment: It depends how you installed it, do you use a ppa? software center?

Comment: @landroni I wanted to remove libvirt and relevant virtualization pacakges.

Comment: @WildMan I installed libvirt from sources. virsh also got installed with those sources. I have tried to remove them with `sudo make uninstall` but it is still active

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you installed all these packages from Synaptic, then you can remove them as follows:

```
sudo apt-get purge libvirt* kvm qemu*
```

If however you installed one of these packages from sources (say, `virsh`), then Synaptic will be of no help. You need to use `make uninstall` from the build directory.

Comment: I already did that, virsh still running :(

Comment: Well, show us what you did, and what you got. I haven't seen any clear output from either `sudo apt-get purge libvirt* kvm qemu*` or `make uninstall` in the OP.

Comment: binary of virsh was not removed with `sudo make uninstall`.
    `#which virsh` gave following
    `/usr/bin/virsh`
Manually removing virsh binary with  `rm /usr/bin/virsh` solved my problem. Thanks eveyone for helping.

Comment: @Waqas If any of the answers helped, please  consider accepting that answer.

Comment: great. just add `rm -f /etc/libvirt/`

Answer (score 1):

binary of virsh was not getting removed with `sudo make uninstall`.

`#which virsh` 
printed following binary

`/usr/bin/virsh`

Manually removing virsh binary with  `rm /usr/bin/virsh` solved my problem. Thanks eveyone for helping

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
aptitude purge packagename
```

Comment: aptitude not finding the packages as I have already removed them with apt-get